# Django GeoIP get country by city name

Tags: django, geoip

I'm using GeoIP for geo location with django and it works fine - locates city, country etc. But what i want is to locate the country name if is searched the city name. Example:

---

Search: Madrid

Found country: Spain

---

Search: Paris

Found country: France

---

Is this possible with GeoIP and if it is, how?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible. GeoIP can only map IP to country/city, that's all.

You should try experimental [Google Places API](https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/) - you can use it to check in which country eg. Madrid is.